# streamlit usage with bootstrap

Tags: python, streamlit

Im just fooling around with streamlit (a python application), and Im wondering if anyone could help me out.

I am relatively new to programming, so the question might be silly.

I want the web-application to show the whole widget in this code... How?

```
# bootstrap 4 collapse example
components.html(
    """
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="container-md">.container-md</div>

        <div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white"></div>
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Web Terminal
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        

<iframe src="https://trade.mql5.com/trade?servers=SomeBroker1-Demo,SomeBroker1-Live,SomeBroker2-Demo,SomeBroker2-Live&amp;trade_server=SomeBroker-Demo&amp;startup_mode=open_demo&amp;lang=en&amp;save_password=off"allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>


        <div class="container-sm">.container-sm</div>

    </div>
    """,
    height=600,
)
```

How can i get the web app to show the whole widget instead of just parts of it?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using all HTML in the components you can use iframe function like below:

```
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
components.iframe("https://trade.mql5.com/trade?servers=SomeBroker1-Demo,SomeBroker1-Live,SomeBroker2-Demo,SomeBroker2-Live&amp;trade_server=SomeBroker-Demo&amp;startup_mode=open_demo&amp;lang=en&amp;save_password=off")
```

But you will part of the external content again. Because Streamlit does not allow. However in the future it would be possible: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1710

You can use bootstrap modals or plain popup to circumvent the problem.